# Kernel Panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(1,0)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, toshiba-laptop

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 16.04.2 on my laptop and i keep getting the following error "
Kernel Panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(1,0)
"

I was running Kodibuntu [previously and before that i was running windows 10.

i was getting the error and i thought it was a hard drive issue so i installed a new hard drive and im getting the same error.

It is a Toshiba Satellite laptop.

Please help.

Comment: This is a well-known problem. Read here, https://askubuntu.com/a/48516/207983

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps and check again. Start with a livecd, open the terminal,

sudo fdisk -l

sudo mount /dev/sdax /mnt

sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev

sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts

sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc

sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys

sudo chroot /mnt

and now you can make update-initramfs and update-grub without errors.

update-initramfs -u -k 2.6.38-8-generic (or your version)

If you don't know your kernel version. Use:

dpkg --list | grep linux-image

And just update Grub.

update-grub2

Reboot your system and have a check.